# Is indirect negative evidence better than direct negative evidence?

Tags: teaching-methods

It is a tendency among teachers to correct students' mistakes directly.

For example, when a student says, **My father goed to the office**, the teacher  blames the student.

Since it is a sign of learning  and  the student  has learnt to use the morpheme *ed* but he did not know that *go* is an irregular verb. The teacher might say, "You are correct. Your father went to the office."

I think it is motherese, which is the talk between a mother and her child when it is acquiring its mother tongue in an informal and caring way.

My question is:

> **Is indirect negative evidence better than direct negative evidence?**

Direct negative evidence means saying that  something is wrong directly to the child by the teacher.

In my question, **My father goed to the office** the teacher did not say that the student was wrong directly but corrected  indirectly by uttering the correct word  went.

Even  in native English speaking countries the child utters goed instead of went it was acquiring the language. So it is natural for nonnative speakers to make the same mistake. It happens with regard to irregular verbs even in native English speaking countries.

What usually happens in the class is  teacher says to the student that  goed is wrong. It should be corrected as went. And even says you are coining new words and so on.

Some linguists say that direct negative evidence does not help in the correction of grammatical mistakes by the learners.

In motherse  the mother does not correct the child.

For example if the child says "It is a crow" instead of a cuckoo, the mother  says  cuckoo  but does not say that it is not a crow but it is a  cuckoo.

Linguists say that if the instruction is like motherse and  indirect, negative evidence language acquisition takes place naturally.

I think it is possible and preferrable to use indirect negative in the language class room.

I attach  here a link to make things clear:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_evidence_in_language_acquisition

Comment: @K Man.I have given a detailed explanation. but it is  not  clear  to  you.If  you  know  please  try  to  answer  my  question

Comment: Your question as originally posted did not give a detailed explanation. Now it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Spanish teacher, I sometimes show my students a list of sentences that reflect commonly made errors and ask them to find and correct the error in each sentence. This is direct negative evidence without the emotional disadvantages of correcting students in the moment during a speaking activity. At the same time, I'm not singling out any individual students for their errors. Even those who never make such errors benefit metacognitively. Therefore, direct negative evidence is preferable. Save indirect negative evidence for speaking activities and informal writing assessments.

Comment: +1 for "show my students a list of sentences that reflect commonly made errors and ask them to find and correct the error in each sentence. ... without the emotional disadvantages of correcting students in the moment during a speaking activity.